# Building a URL with comma separated query parameters using httr

Tags: r, httr

I am building an API wrapper in which I am using `httr` for the bulk of the work.  The URL for the API uses commas to separate more than 1 choice to a query parameter.

My current code uses `glue::glue` and `stringr` to tidy the vector in order to build the URL.  Is there a way to use `httr` to build the URL including the commas in the `httr::GET` command?

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

idPlayerMLB <- c("677551", "650402")
hydrate <- c("awards", "currentTeam")

# MLB API is https://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1/people/
base_url <- "https://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1/people?"

# fix id to string
ids <- stringr::str_c(idPlayerMLB, collapse = ",")
hydrations <- stringr::str_c(hydrate, collapse = ",")

url <- glue::glue("{base_url}personIds={ids}&hydrate={hydrations}") %>% as.character()

url
#> [1] "https://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1/people?personIds=677551,650402&hydrate=awards,currentTeam"

# Get URL
resp <- httr::GET(base_url,
  query = list(
    personIds = stringr::str_c(idPlayerMLB, collapse = ","),
    hydrate = stringr::str_c(hydrate, collapse = ",")
  )
)

# print URL
resp$url
#> [1] "https://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1/people?personIds=677551%2C650402&hydrate=awards%2CcurrentTeam"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Are you just worred about the `%2C` part? Because that's just a URL encoded comma. The link returned there gives the same data as the one with a literal comma for me. I'm not sure I see what the problem is here.

Comment: There’s no problem, it was more about style, and whether there was already a way to achieve what I’m looking for within the.

Comment: httr is really doing the right thing here. A comma is a reserved character for URLs and should not be used as data in a querystring parameter in its unescaped form. Seems odd to try to change the correct behavior. You could run `URLdecode(resp$url)` to make it look more like you might expect.